# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast using MultipartRequest in Flutter

Tags: http, flutter, dart, xmlhttprequest, dart-pub

I'm trying to send a POST request with the following body:

```
{
  name_en: TV, 
  name_ar: تلفزز, 
  description_en: Big TV, 
  description_ar: للفو, 
  price_cents: 14300, 
  discount_price_cents: null, 
  sub_category_id: 2,
  quantity: 12,
  status: available,
  featured: false,
  gender_compatibility: any,
  seller_id: 2, 
  stocks: {
            color_id: 2, 
            size_id: 2, 
            stock_quantity: 11
           }
 }
```

But I keep receiving the error above. I know the error is because of the nested 'stocks' in the request but I'm not able to find a way to parse it and make it work yet.

Here's the code block:

```
var uri = Uri.parse(
          '${Constants.kHostUrl}$url?auth_key=${Constants.kAUTH_KEY}');
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
request.fields.addAll(object.cast<String, String>());
request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', image));
var response = await request.send();
```

The error occurs at `request.fields.addAll(object.cast<String, String>());`

Comment: Your map contains different kinds of objects like strings, numbers and booleans and can therefore not just be casted to containing Strings.

Comment: @julemand101 The code works fine without 'stocks' object as I set the objects type to dynamic. But the problem with 'stocks' is that it contains other objects inside it.

Comment: Why not convert the Map into JSON and send the JSON string to the web service?

Comment: @julemand101 I tried to convert it using `jsonEncode` but then `fields.addAll` provides me with `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'`

Comment: Ok, but how does this API works? The fields on the request can only be Map<String,String> so you need to figure out how to represent the stocks field. Maybe it should be JSON formatted?